# Why am I unable to access subnodes of my JSON using SQL?

Tags: json, sql-server

I'm going a bit mad with this one, and I'm sure it'll be something easily spotted by someone not staring at it for the last hour...

I have the following JSON (there are more examples of 'Details' but two should suffice for this question:

```
[
    {
        "MonthDetails": [
            {
                "Month": 1,
                "MonthName": "January 2020",
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "ServiceUserName": "Resident 1",
                        "ServiceUserLastName": "Resident",
                        "SUID": "b5259252-2018-43ee-a7a9-842fa7c80473",
                        "InfectionType": "Urinary tract",
                        "DateStarted": "2019-11-05T13:53:01.9392086+00:00",
                        "DateCleared": "Open",
                        "NextReviewDate": "2019-11-06T13:53:01.9392086+00:00",
                        "AntibioticsStartDate": "2019-11-05T00:00:00+00:00",
                        "AntibioticsEndDate": "2019-11-07T00:00:00+00:00",
                        "AcquiredOnAdmission": false,
                        "NeedsBarrierNursing": false,
                        "IsOpen": true,
                        "DaysToClear": 0,
                        "SURecordOpen": true
                    },
                    {
                        "ServiceUserName": "Resident 2",
                        "ServiceUserLastName": "Resident",
                        "SUID": "376cffba-52ce-4de0-855d-dd9e24f466e0",
                        "InfectionType": "Chest",
                        "DateStarted": "2019-12-04T12:11:30.7777465+00:00",
                        "DateCleared": "Open",
                        "NextReviewDate": "2019-12-05T12:11:30.7777465+00:00",
                        "AntibioticsStartDate": "2019-12-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                        "AntibioticsEndDate": "2019-12-08T00:00:00+00:00",
                        "AcquiredOnAdmission": true,
                        "NeedsBarrierNursing": false,
                        "IsOpen": true,
                        "DaysToClear": 0,
                        "SURecordOpen": true
                    }
                ],
                "criteria": null,
                "Errors": {},
                "DateFrom": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "SelectedDateRange": null,
                "NumberOfDays": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My understanding was that if I wanted to get eg. MonthDetails.Details >> ServiceUserName, SUID, etc, I could use the following code:

```
SELECT * INTO Residents FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$.MonthDetails.Details') 
    WITH
    (   
        ServiceUserName nvarchar(100) '$.ServiceUserName',
        ServiceUserLastName nvarchar(100) '$.ServiceUserName',
        SUID nvarchar(150) '$.SUID',
        InfectionType nvarchar(30) '$.InfectionType',
        DateStarted nvarchar(10) '$.DateStarted',
        DateCleared nvarchar(10) '$.DateCleared',
        NextReviewDate nvarchar(10) '$.NextReviewDate',
        AntibioticsStartDate nvarchar(10) '$.AntibioticsStartDate',
        AntibioticsEndDate nvarchar(10) '$.AntibioticsEndDate',
        AcquiredOnAdmission nvarchar(5) '$.AcquiredOnAdmission',
        NeedsBarrierNursing nvarchar(5) '$.NeedsBarrierNursing',
        IsOpen nvarchar(5) '$.IsOpen',
        DaysToClear nvarchar(5) '$.DaysToClear',
        SURecordOpen nvarchar(5) '$.SURecordOpen'
    )
```

However, all that happens is that one record is creating one entry with NULL in every column. I'm aware that I can just do $.MonthDetails and then pass the Details as JSON through and cross apply it, but I thought the preferred method above should work too?

Thanks
Ant

Comment: Square brackets `[]` indicate arrays. Have you tried using something like `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$[0].MonthDetails[0].Details[0]') ...` ?

Comment: I hadn't, actually. I should've! The structure will only ever be 0 and 1, so that might be something I try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have 2 arrays inside `MonthDetails`, I assume you want 2 rows. Therefore it seems like what you are actually after might be this:

```
SELECT D.*
--Get first array, using [0], as pointed out by AlwaysLearning
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$[0].MonthDetails')
        WITH (Details nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) OJ
    --Now parse the inner data
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OJ.Details)
        WITH (ServiceUserName nvarchar(100) '$.ServiceUserName',
              ServiceUserLastName nvarchar(100) '$.ServiceUserName',
              SUID nvarchar(150) '$.SUID', --Should this not be a uniqueidentifier?
                                           --Why an nvarchar(150) when a uniqueidentifer is a 36 characters which all can be displayed with a varchar?
              InfectionType nvarchar(30) '$.InfectionType',
              DateStarted nvarchar(10) '$.DateStarted', --Should this not be a date?
              DateCleared nvarchar(10) '$.DateCleared', --Should this not be a date?
              NextReviewDate nvarchar(10) '$.NextReviewDate', --Should this not be a date?
              AntibioticsStartDate nvarchar(10) '$.AntibioticsStartDate', --Should this not be a date?
              AntibioticsEndDate nvarchar(10) '$.AntibioticsEndDate', --Should this not be a date?
              AcquiredOnAdmission nvarchar(5) '$.AcquiredOnAdmission', --Why an nvarchar when it can only be true or false?
              NeedsBarrierNursing nvarchar(5) '$.NeedsBarrierNursing',--Why an nvarchar when it can only be true or false?
              IsOpen nvarchar(5) '$.IsOpen',
              DaysToClear nvarchar(5) '$.DaysToClear', --Should this not be an int?
              SURecordOpen nvarchar(5) '$.SURecordOpen') D; --Why an nvarchar when it can only be true or false?
```

Note I strongly recommend changing to the correct data type, which i have commented on.

Comment: Thanks. This is the code that I ended up trying and gave me the results I needed. For some reason I never thought of just asking for the SECOND result set instead of just select * from at the top level. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

for single objects in arrays and multiple Details

```
select *
from openjson(@json, '$[0].MonthDetails[0].Details')
with
(
    ServiceUserName varchar(50),
    ServiceUserLastName varchar(50),
    SUID uniqueidentifier,
    InfectionType varchar(50),
    DateStarted datetimeoffset(7),
    DaysToClear int
);
```

for any number of objects in the arrays (adjust for the rest of the elements/objects)

```
select *
from openjson(@json) AS t
cross apply openjson(t.value)
with 
(
    MonthDetails nvarchar(max) as json
) AS md
cross apply openjson(md.MonthDetails)
with
(
    [Month] tinyint,
    MonthName varchar(20),
    criteria varchar(50),
    DateFrom datetime2(0),
    SelectedDateRange varchar(10),
    NumberOfDays int,
    Details nvarchar(max) as json
) as mdd
cross apply openjson (mdd.Details)
with
(
    ServiceUserName varchar(50),
    ServiceUserLastName varchar(50),
    SUID uniqueidentifier,
    InfectionType varchar(50),
    DateStarted datetimeoffset(7),
    DaysToClear int
    --,...............
) as det;
```

Comment: Thanks. As I said, I'm aware I'm able to do this, I just thought (and must've misread other information on the net telling me this) that I could just do $.MonthDetails.Details and then access the info in the sub nodes. Thank you though.

Comment: i see, my mistake, you can do that, but only for single array parent objects (and multiple Details). Answer edited

Comment: Thank you. You and AlwaysLearning seem to be along the same lines there. Yeah I might try this, so I'll see what fits best and update. Thank you for your help! It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this unexpected result in your example is the fact, that you have a JSON structure, that includes nested JSON arrays and you don't have an object or array, that can be parsed with `OPENJSON()` and path like `'$.MonthDetails.Details'`. In this case, you need to use an additional `APPLY` operator and `OPENJSON()` call to parse the nested JSON arrays.

The statement in the question will work, if you have a JSON with the following format ( the whole JSON and the `"MonthDetails"` key are JSON objects, not JSON arrays):

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SELECT @json = N'{
        "MonthDetails": {
                "Month": 1,
                "MonthName": "January 2020",
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "ServiceUserName": "Resident 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "ServiceUserName": "Resident 2"
                    }
                ],
                "NumberOfDays": 0
            }
}'
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.MonthDetails.Details') WITH (
   ServiceUserName nvarchar(100) '$.ServiceUserName' 
   /*, ... other columns */
)
```

To parse the JSON correctly, you should use the following statement:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SELECT @json = N'[
    {
        "MonthDetails": [
            {
                "Month": 1,
                "MonthName": "January 2020",
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "ServiceUserName": "Resident 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "ServiceUserName": "Resident 2"
                    }
                ],
                "NumberOfDays": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]'
SELECT j2.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$[0].MonthDetails') WITH (
   Details nvarchar(max) '$.Details' AS JSON
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.Details, '$') WITH (
   ServiceUserName nvarchar(100) '$.ServiceUserName' 
   /*, ... other columns */
) j2
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, as I said in my question. I just thought you could circumvent the cross apply part through having the $.Node.Subnode, such as described here https://sql-server.programmingpedia.net/en/tutorial/5030/openjson . I know the difference between an array and object, but was curious as to why what seemed like it would work, wasn't.

Comment: @Ant OK, I understand. In this case the short answer to your question is that you receive rows with `NULL` values because you don't have object or array, that can be parsed with `'$.MonthDetails.Details'` as path.